# Is $k(x, x') = 1$ if $x = x' $ and $k(x, x') = 0$ otherwise a valid kernel function?

Tags: kernel-trick

Is $k(x, x') = 1$ if $x = x' $ and $k(x, x') = 0$ otherwise a valid kernel function? I can't prove the Gram matrix is positive semi-definite. I was wondering if we can find a basis function $\phi: X \to R^m$ such that $k(x, x') = \phi(x)^T\phi(x')$? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the Gram matrix just the identity matrix for this kernel?

Comment: @guy why is that? What if there are duplicates in the dataset?

Comment: If you allow duplicates, just permute so that it is a blockwise diagonal matrix with blocks given by matrices of $1$'s. A blockwise diagonal matrix of PSD matrices is also PSD.

Comment: @guy Thanks for the reply! Could you elaborate on what you mean by permute and what the blockwise diagonal matrix would look like? I was wondering if there is a way to write a basis function tho.

Comment: Imagine you have $x, y, z$ with $x = z$. Then the Gram matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. You can permute the rows and columns to get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ without altering whether it is PSD (row/column permutations correspond to invertible linear transforms). The second matrix is obviously PSD. My point is that you can do this in general. And I don't think using a basis expansion is the right tool for this unless $X$ is finite or countable.

Comment: I see your point! Thanks!